# Почему пропадает сессия в CodeIgniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

День добрый

пишу авторизацию в codeigniter3

Писал и через БД и через нативные и через CI сессии - везде одна и та же проблема

ситуация такая :

авторизую пользователя

вывожу его значение сессии

[__ci_last_regenerate] => 1441008949

далее [id] [login] и т п

далее

если открыть в соседней вкладке сайт - то сессия пропадает и значение
[__ci_last_regenerate] => 1441008941 (другое)

НО

стоит перейти по любой ссылке - сессия восстанавливается

Почему при первом входе он забывает пользователя ?

Comment: Включайте в браузере инструменты разработчика (сеть) и проверяйте, что у вас приходит от сервера в куках.